# Which view is fragment attached in ViewPager using FragmentStateAdapter?

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Fragment needs to be attached to a view but using viewpager, that is handled automatically. My question is how? which layout file is tablayout attach the fragment to?